# Have Flask not answer a request and deliberately leave the client hanging

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I would like my Flask app to ignore some requests to an endpoint and not answer them, not even with an error. The effect I'm looking for is to deliberately have the client hanging (this is to demonstrate something a bit esoteric but too long to explain in details here - it's absolutely not for prod. or anything important and I'm aware it goes against everything a sane app should do!).

I'm hoping I can achieve this with Flask somehow, even if it's hacky.

Is there any way I can trick Flask to do absolutely nothing, kill it's thread, leave the client hanging, and continue with normal operations for all other requests? IE:

```
@app.route('/hang')
def hang():
    # do absolutely nothing and continue normal operations
    # don't return 500 or anything
```

Comment: A black hole redirect might work, according to [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49816007/1290627).

Answer (score 0):

I was also wondering about this as a way to have a more "invisible" server, and I didn't find much great advice here. Could a simple sleep work here?

```
import time

@app.route('/hang')
def hang():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1000)
    return
```

Run from my local PC, the above code with sleep will prevent other requests from being processed. This seems okay since you mentioned it is not for production, and I know that using mod_wsgi in production each client gets their own thread so it would not block simultaneous requests. So perhaps, since you are only using this locally and may need to handle multiple simultaneous requests, you might be able to do some multithreading so it is non-blocking.